# front end editing using iFrames, best approach?

Tags: admin, user-access, front-end

I was going to give users back end access to edit entries but don't like the idea of them having access to the back end. I currently am using/developing with Adminize and Role Scooper and have set up custom editing screens for the users. Users will have access to a custom post type for their user profile and to a single custom post type for their company profile page. My site is a directory of companies.

What I would like to have is the ability to load in the custom editing pages from the back end into iFrames on the front end via an edit menu on the custom post page.

I assume I will need to use AJAX in some form or another. I have looked at a few front end editing plugins but they seem to all fall short f what I need/am looking for.

1. Is it possible to load in the back end editing pages into iFrames?
2. Can I save the edits and reload the front end page simultaneously? I think I can but unsure of how to approach it.
3. Is there a better way of accomplishing this?

Thanks for any insights and suggestion you may have!

Comment: You may find http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/front-end-editor/ useful

Comment: I tried that one but fell short in what I needed. But I did take some ideas form the code. Thanks :)

Comment: @dkmojo I like your question and wants do the same, I am usinf Contactform7 and i want to give access some user to create form using frontend. How it can possible ?

Comment: @AjayPatel I stopped using ContactForm7 but you can do it by creating your own forms and using wp_update_post function to update the post as the form submits. If you don't want to create your own forms you can use GravityForms plugin - http://www.gravityforms.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a custom template and [`wp_update_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post) you should be able to build your own edit/add post pages in your sites frontend. There are also various plugins available that attempt to do similar things.

iFrames can be done, but it will need some checks in functions.php to check for a get variable and add conditional stylesheets to hide the menus etc. Any users able to do this would also be able to bypass this and go directly to the backend themselves.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the info on iFrames. I did briefly look into using a template on the front end so it looks like I will be going back to that idea/plan. The one thing I could not get to work right is the Featured Image. I could get it to upload and save but could not get the image to show up in my "upload" box. A little more research will be involved here I think. Thanks again!

Comment: there are functions in wordpress that you can use to handle the upload and saving of attachments, after which it's simply setting a custom field